# How to create new columns in QGIS by writng Conditional query on other columns of attributes table

Tags: qgis

First of all, sorry, I couldn't phrase my question better.

So I want to be able to add a new column in my attributes table, say B, and it's value should be 1 if Column A's value is 1 and 0 if Column A's value is 2. in other words:

If A==1 : B=1

elif A==2 : B=2
I couldn't figure out a way to do this using Field Calculator.

Thanks
[image: Trying to update "MineDeleteIt" values based on path_type]

Comment: After the THEN it should be `'Bike lane baby'` and also `'some arbitrary text'`.  You need single quotes for strings

Comment: You are right. I had added double quotes and it didn't make any difference. Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: Double quotes are for column names. Single quotes for strings.

Comment: @NathanW Sorry for pushing this, but do if-else conditions work too? I'm getting errors, but if it's possible I'll figure it out myself...

Comment: Not yet. We haven't added support yet.  Feel free to open at ticket at http://hub.qgis.org/ and assign it to me. I'm the only Nathan in the list.

Comment: Great! thanks for your help. I'll "open at ticket at hub.qgis.org and assign it" to you, but I first have to do some research to see what it means :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case statement to do that:

```
CASE 
    WHEN "A" = 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN "A" = 2 THEN 2 
END
```

If you want everything else to match you can use `ELSE`

```
CASE 
    WHEN "A" = 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN "A" = 2 THEN 2
    ELSE 0
END
```

This way everything that is not A=1 or A=2 will get assigned 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell me where should I enter it though? should I use field Calculator? Because it says invalid expression...

Comment: Which version of QGIS?

Comment: it's 1.8. are u able to do it with field calculator?

Comment: Yes.  What does it say when you click (More INfo)

Comment: it say's : Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting WHEN or ELSE or END

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: Can you upload a screen shot of your field calculator dialog with the expression.

Comment: I edited the question and added the screenshot